# .each not iterating properly over array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two ruby classes for storing some custom logs in a game.
`RoundLog` contains information related to a single round and `BattleLog` is just an array that contains multiple `RoundLog` elements.

```
class RoundLog
  attr_writer :actions, :number

  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
    @actions = []
  end
  def to_a
    [@number, @actions]
  end
  ...
end

class BattleLog
  attr_accessor :rounds
  def initialize
    @rounds = []
  end
  def print
    @rounds.each do |round|
      round.to_a
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

If I have the following `BattleLog` instance:

```
report = [#<RoundLog:0x00000008ab8328 @number=1, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,
#<RoundLog:0x00000008acc170 @number=2, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,
#<RoundLog:0x00000008aef5f8 @number=3, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,
#<RoundLog:0x00000008b02978 @number=4, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,
#<RoundLog:0x00000008b1a280 @number=5, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage"]>]
```

Then the following piece of code is not working: `report.each {|x| x.to_a}`
Instead of returning properly formatted information like that:

```
[1, ["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"],
[2, ["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"], ...]
```

It returns the whole RoundLog object:

```
[#<RoundLog:0x00000008ab8328 @number=1, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,
#<RoundLog:0x00000008acc170 @number=2, @actions=["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]>,...]
```

However, if I try something like this: `report.first.to_a` it's properly returning `[1, ["Rat hits Test and deals 1 points of damage", "Test hits Rat and deals 1 points of damage"]`
Any idea what is wrong with my code ?
I tried renaming the `to_a` to something else, so I don't think the problem is with function name. It's my first question on SO, so please be indulgent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `map` instead of `each` should solve your problem.

`each` runs some operations inside the block and then returns the object/array/hash/enumerable/whatever that `each` was called upon. `map` however returns a new array with the return values calculated in your block.

Comment: Thanks, it's working :) I really missed that important difference between `each` and `map` (I thought the problem is somewhere else).